# how to make array of different objects work well with NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array of different objects. One object is `CTVMenuItem` which has a `menuHeaderID`. I'd like to get all the items which have a `menuHeaderID` of `12` AND are of `Class` `CTVMenuItem`. How would I do this?

I have:

```
  // lets test this
  NSMutableArray *testArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  // lets add an item
  CTVMenuHeader *mh1=[[CTVMenuHeader alloc] init];
  mh1.name=@"menu-header 1";
  [testArray addObject:mh1];

  CTVMenuItem *mi1=[[CTVMenuItem alloc] init];
  mi1.name=@"sub1 - menu item name #1";
  mi1.menuHeaderID=@11;
  [testArray addObject:mi1];

  CTVMenuItem *mi2=[[CTVMenuItem alloc] init];
  mi2.name=@"sub1 - menu item name #2";
  mi2.menuHeaderID=@12;
  [testArray addObject:mi2];

  NSLog(@"here is array %@", testArray);
  // ?????
  NSArray *selected=[testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"menuHeaderID == %i", 12]];
  NSLog(@"here is selected %@", selected);
```

Comment: I've edited the question, as I assume you meant that the objects must be of `Class` `CTVMenuItem` instead of `CTVMenuHeader`. Please correct me if I've assumed wrong.

Comment: thx, honestly either way is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example above, you want:

```
[testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"(class == %@) AND (menuHeaderID == %i)",
  [CTVMenuItem class],
  12]];
```

Note that you must test the object type first, before checking `menuHeaderID`. Swap the two around to see why.